# Remove html element which not contains specific class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to remove li's with not active state, but cant make it work:

```
var html = $("#myjqgriddiv").remove("ul li:not(.ui-state-active)").html();
```

I have html and i want to remove li which not contains class `.ui-state-active`

After code above the li with .ui-state-active still there.

Need help.

UPDATE:

My intention to that html i am going to print using `window.open("","Print")/document.write`

@tvanfosson answer is working but there is one more little thing, the single li which stayed after first modification i want to edit as well i want to remove attribute "href" from its `a` child

```
var html = $('#myjqgriddiv') // select div
                .find('ul li:not(.ui-state-active)') // select elements to remove from div
                .remove()  // remove the matched elements
                .end() // revert back to the originally selected elements
                .html(); // and get the HTML


html = $(html).find("ul li.ui-state-active a)").removeAttr("href").html(); // not working?!
```

Comment: What is your intention with the .html?  For those who are trying to answer your question with a code snippet, this is important.  I think the answer provided by @tvanfosson addresses your intent.  Please clarify so we can be sure.

Comment: You don't want to put `html` into the dollar function, you want to select `#myjqgriddiv` again.  The `html` variable is just text that is not attached to the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to remove acts as a filter, not a selector.  Since you've only selected the one element with id `mygqgriddiv`, the filter removes nothing.  Try.

```
 var html = $('#myjqgriddiv') // select div
                .find('ul li:not(.ui-state-active)') // select elements to remove from div
                .remove()  // remove the matched elements
                .end() // revert back to the originally selected elements
                .find("ul li.ui-state-active a)") // now get the active ones
                .removeAttr("href") // remove the href attribute
                .end() // back to the original selection
                .html(); // and get the HTML
```

Comment: @jason - it works as a filter to match elements in the collection of elements already selected.  It doesn't add elements to the collection.  Your original selector wouldn't have selected those elements and so the filter matched nothing and nothing was removed.

Comment: This can be shortened to `$("#myjqgriddiv li:not(.ui-state-active)").remove();`. Short n simple.

Comment: @Clarkey - except that he wants to select the HTML out of the DIV at the end.  To do that, you have to start with just the selector for the DIV.  If that weren't the case, then your version would be better.

Comment: @jason -- looks like you have an extra parenthesis in the selector.

Comment: @tvanfosson yes you right, but after removed that this selector `$(html).find("ul li.ui-state-active a").removeAttr("href").html();` just returned only text() of that `a`, everything else disappeared.

Comment: @json - you need to use the `end()` again to get back to the original selection before getting the html. I'll update.

Comment: @tvanfosson yes i tried to go like that `$(html).find("ul li.ui-state-active a").removeAttr("href").end().html();` in such case i have just `a` tag, but all the rest is still gone.

Comment: @jason - that's because `html` is not a jquery or DOM element, but a string.  See how I've done the chaining so that it retains the original selector.

Comment: @jason - btw, since you're new, once you have an answer that you feel best answers your question, you should click the check mark next to it and mark it as accepted.  This gives the answerer 15pt bonus and you a 2pt bonus...and helps others who find your question know which answer you found most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) will only remove elements from the selected list.  Put the two selectors into the `$` function and remove the result.

```
var html = $("#myjqgriddiv ul li:not(.ui-state-active)").remove().html();
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to get the HTML of the removed elements.  I think it should be the HTML of the div without the removed elements.

Comment: It's possible, but unclear from the question.  My answer was focused on the problem with `remove`.